# Swift NSString to Int conversion issues

Tags: swift, command-line, terminal, nsstring, integer

First off, I'm fairly new to programming and trying to learn Swift, though I've worked with python and perl in the past.

I'm creating a simple prime number command line application. The program runs correctly when I provide the arguments for the functions, but causes consistently incorrect outputs when I prompt user input.  I researched the best way to implement this behavior in Swift, as it doesn't have `scanf()` or `raw_input()` type commands, but I have something screwed up.

The program has several different functions, but the one I've been fighting with checks whether an integer is prime.  The code for the function follows:

```
func testForPrime(num:Int)->Bool{
    var num = num
    var counter = 0
    var primeTest : Bool = true

    if num <= 1 || num % 2 == 0{
        println("\(num) is not a prime number")
        primeTest = false
    }else{
    ##'checkerNumbers' is another function to determine the denominator 
        for i in checkerNumbers(Double(num)){ 
            if num % i == 0 {
                ++counter
                println("\(num) is not a prime number.")
                println("\(num / i)*\(i)=\(num)")
                primeTest = false
                break
            }
        }
        if counter == 0{
            println("\(num) is a prime number!")
            primeTest = true
        }
    }
    return primeTest
}
```

And here is the ***input*** for the function:

```
var input = NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput()

println("Enter a number to check if it is prime")

if let data : NSData = input.availableData as NSData? { 
    if let var x : Int = NSInteger(NSUTF8StringEncoding) as NSInteger?{
        var intInput = x
        testForPrime(intInput)        
    }
}
```

When a *any* number is entered in the terminal, the output is always '4'.  However, if I run the function with `testForPrime(13)`, instead of with user input, it responds as I would expect. I was thinking it may have to do with the conversion from NSString and `NSUTF8StringEncoding` to `Int`...

Can someone help me sort this out?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if let var x : Int = NSInteger(NSUTF8StringEncoding) as NSInteger?  ?? this line here makes no sense, you are not using data from the input

Comment: why cast data to data

Comment: Gotcha.. I guess i'm more lost than I thought on the input.  How can I prompt user input from swift? I thought the `NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput()` read the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... So I figured out a way to make it work, though it may not be the best.  I replaced the whole input section with the following:

```
println("Enter a number to check if it is prime")

var input = NSString(data: NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput().availableData, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)

var intInput = input?.intValue

testForPrime(Int(intInput!))
```